# Can structural damage be detected or predicted using historical data?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-structures

Can software simulations and structural health monitoring techniques accurately predict damage occurrence in aerospace structures using historical data(`stiffness,damping and vibration measurements over a considerable period of time`)

or

Are these techniques more suited to real time damage detection rather than damage prediction ?

> For eg. SHM techniques such as parameter estimation using Frequency Response, or Non Destructive Inspection.

Comment: I'm not sure it can accurately predict either. There are a lot of software packages out there that can model structural damage, but I don't know of any real-time damage detection system in use...

Comment: Sounds like a research project (e.g. for studying PhD, anyone?)

Comment: This is the basic principle behind [predictive maintenance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_maintenance) in general. In the aviation industry, adding hundreds of cheap wireless sensors will help in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done. However, with the advent of technologies, you can also use the real time updates of the monitored system to understand it's health. In some cases where the historical data is not available, it becomes important to assess the structure's condition based on real time updates. I feel the following links could be of interest:

1. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1475921718760483
2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0888327017304612

Comment: *"Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and links should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer."* If you could elaborate on how it can be done this might be a much better answer. Also, it would be nice to disclose you are the first and second author on those articles you linked, otherwise this may be flagged as spam.

Answer (score 1):

Since few years, flight data is used to improve predictive maintenance.
This Big Data approach is apparently very popular among airlines.

But structural damage must still be evaluated by hand (and torchlight) from reports.